# Paypal PayFlow payments Error multiple requests

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using the payPal Payflow payment request to credit card transacions.

if I send two requests back-to-back to my API, the second request will receive a null response from the SubmitTransaction method of the Payflownet API.

Why is this happening?

Comment: It might not be necessary for someone who is familiar with the API to answer the question, but is it possible for you to include a [mcve]?